# How to block specific django app's url

Tags: python, django

I'm using the AllAuth plugin.

Is there a proper way to block only a part of it's urls?

Comment: would this help? [Link](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.2/howto/how_to_disable_an_app.html)

Comment: I think you can create all-auth app in your project and override urls.py there. It should be picked up first. But is is just a guess.

Comment: I think both answers do the job. Was looking at something cleaner but I don't think it exists.

Thank you both!